# Python request returning 400, same syntax works in powershell

Tags: python, https, python-requests

```bsh
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://discord.com/api/v6/users/@me/relationships" `
-Method "POST" `
-Headers @{
  "authorization"="Token"
} `
-ContentType "application/json" `
-Body "{`"username`":`"MyUsername`",`"discriminator`":MyDiscriminator(int)}"
```

That works perfectly in powershell

However in python,

```py
import requests

print(requests.post('https://discord.com/api/v6/users/@me/relationships', headers={'authorization':'Token', 'content-type' : 'application/json'}, data={"username":"Username", "discriminator":Discriminator(Int)}))
```

Gives me a 400 error.

Comment: Is it giving error 400 or 404. Your header and text both say different things

Comment: What is `Discriminator(Int)`, in the context of the Python request?

Comment: @gallen It's my discord discriminator, 6318 not as a string but an int.

Comment: @JackTheRipper A 400 HTTP Response is a Bad Request. Do you get anything useful back from the API if you print out the `.text` attribute of the Response object? Sometimes you can determine what's off by the response you get.

Comment: @gallen 'message': '400: Bad Request', 'code': 0 that doesn't give me much.

Comment: Per the [docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/opcodes-and-status-codes) a code 0 when sending JSON means "General error (such as a malformed request body, amongst other things)". That at least gives a starting point of things to tweak.